# OpenCV, drawing depth map

Tags: ros, c++, opencv, image, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I have a little project on C++.

In this project, I I try to find sample image on depth map, received from Kinect. I check results by drawing both images (sample and current scene) in 1 window. Keypoints linked with lines after it. But I can't see current scene in window. Where can be problem? Something wrong  in src/Classifier.cpp, method `void Detector::findObject(cv::Mat scene)`.
And one more question - what method should I use to copy data from one cv::Mat to other? I use cvtColor for this. I think, that class method copyTo() should do same work, but it doesn't. Thanks for help!

Here project - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16807894/robot-vision.zip

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11747/opencv,-drawing-depth-map/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think, that found answer. OpenCV can't deal with different types images. When it tries to draw them in 1 window, only one image will be really shown (tested only with images from Kinect).

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2011-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you still have your project available to download, i am working on the same too

---

Originally posted by [amislaouiandal](https://answers.ros.org/users/12001/amislaouiandal/) with karma: 11 on 2014-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1